# How to get first row value from each group and apply to first record only, rest will be 0 or null in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, ssms-2016

This is our output:

| category | Rev | trandate | BankAccNo | Fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Credit Cards | 1 | 01-09-2022 | 10000175090 | 576 |
| Credit Cards | 1 | 01-09-2022 | 10000175090 | 576 |
| Loan | 2.2 | 01-01-2022 | 10000175090 | 678 |
| Loan | 2.2 | 01-02-2022 | 10000175090 | 678 |
| Loan | 3.4 | 01-03-2022 | 10000175090 | 678 |
| Loan | 2.2 | 01-05-2022 | 10000175090 | 678 |
| Loan | 2.2 | 01-06-2022 | 10000175090 | 678 |
| Loan | 5.81 | 01-08-2022 | 10000175090 | 678 |
| Loan | 2.2 | 01-09-2022 | 10000175090 | 678 |

But we are looking for expected result should be look like mentioned below.

| category | Rev | trandate | BankAccNo | Fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Credit Cards | 1 | 01-09-2022 | 10000175090 | 576 |
| Credit Cards | 1 | 01-09-2022 | 10000175090 | 0 |
| Loan | 2.2 | 01-01-2022 | 10000175090 | 678 |
| Loan | 2.2 | 01-02-2022 | 10000175090 | 0 |
| Loan | 3.4 | 01-03-2022 | 10000175090 | 0 |
| Loan | 2.2 | 01-05-2022 | 10000175090 | 0 |
| Loan | 2.2 | 01-06-2022 | 10000175090 | 0 |
| Loan | 5.81 | 01-08-2022 | 10000175090 | 0 |
| Loan | 2.2 | 01-09-2022 | 10000175090 | 0 |

Final result would look like 2nd table mentioned on the above.

Comment: First record based on what criteria? Tables and rows have no implicit order. You can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY .. ORDER ...)` to find the first row in a specific partition but you *must* specify the order by which you decide what the first row is

Comment: Keep the data in the question itself, not as links to who knows where

Comment: based on BankAccNo and min trandate

Comment: You may be able to write `IIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BankAccNo, Category ORDER BY TranDate) =1),Fee,0) As Fee`. If the database complains you may have to use a CTE to calculate the row number

Answer (score 2):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` along with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT category, Rev, trandate, BankAccNo,
       CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category, BankAccNo ORDER BY trandate) = 1
            THEN Fee ELSE 0 END AS Fee
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY 1, 5;
```

In the event that two or more records from the same category happen to fall on the same earliest transaction date, then only one of those records will arbitrarily report the actual fee value, with the other tie records reporting 0.